# What happens when you solve the second Maze/Tower puzzle?

Tags: the-witness

There's a "castle" with two areas, both of which contain four mazes. In between the areas is a tower with a laser.

On top of that tower, there are two puzzles. The first requires the solutions to the first area an actives the laser. To solve the second puzzle, you actually don't seem to need to have solved the mazes in the second area (although I have). I've solved this second puzzle on top of the tower, but I didn't notice any effect of solving this.

So, does solving the second puzzle on top of the tower trigger anything?

BTW, I didn't notice any effect of having solved the fourth puzzle in the second area (the puzzle with two "L" pieces). Did it enable the second tower puzzle?

Comment: ...and yes, solving the fourth puzzle should have activated its respective puzzle on the tower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only have to solve one of the two puzzles to activate the beam.  Either one will work.

As far as I can tell, solving the second only increases your puzzles solved count.

Comment: I'm nearly finished with the game, I can confirm this is almost certainly correct.

Comment: They are also some hidden puzzles in the castle which relate to the mentioned puzzles.

Comment: I can confirm this also. The Keep is a neat area, and activating the laser only requires completing one of the two puzzles. The only reason to complete both sides is the joy of it all, and going for 100% completion.